# ObjectID showing Unicode gibberish instead of a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unicode, webstorm

When I debug my Node application, my ObjectId's are represented by Unicode gibberish like `ObjectID {id: RýÕ/H}` instead of the actual readable ID. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxxpd.png). Does anyone know what's causing this?

I am using WebStorm 7.0.1 on Crunchbang Waldorf x64.

**UPDATE:** After checking in node-inspector, I get the same results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANw50.png

The only time I can see my ObjectId's properly is if I check them in Robomongo (a MongoDB GUI) or if I log them to the console from within the Node app.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it's just the way WebStorm currently works. You can do a quick evaluate using `object.toString()` when debugging if you need it. Instead of WebStorm showing something friendly, it's showing the binary representation of the `ObjectID.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while doing a Node.js and MongoDB exercise from this book: https://leanpub.com/nodecraftsman. The code I'm talking about is on page 83, line 12.

I was running and testing everything through the command line.

What I discovered was that one line of the code (line #12) contained console.dir(documents). I changed it to console.log(documents), and it gave me back an id I expected -- something like 54e95c6f322fd679214d3a18 rather than the gibberish of, for example, Té\o2/Öy!M:\u0015

MDN describes console.dir() as "nonstandard," so perhaps there was something odd going on. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in WebStorm. They are tracking the issue here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9945